# Forbid record index type conversion in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

At the moment in TypeScript it is possible to write:

```
const r: Record<string, string> = {
  "42": "42_value"
};
console.log(r[42]);
```

Prints:

```
"42_value"
```

Can I somehow forbid passing number as index to `Record<string, string>` index operator and disable automatic conversion of `number` to `string`? Or maybe I should use some other type instead of `Record` to strongly specify key type and force compiler error on line `console.log(r[42])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to forbid with help of extra function:

```js
type NotNumber<T> = keyof T extends `${number}` ? never : keyof T extends number ? never : T

const forbidNumber = <
  Key extends string | number,
  Dict extends Record<Key, string>
>(arg: NotNumber<Dict>) => arg

forbidNumber({ 42: 'hello' }) // error
forbidNumber({ '42': 'hello' }) // error

forbidNumber({ '42foo': 'hello' }) // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sGBXAtgIwgJwDwBUB8UAvFANYQhwBmUuUEAHsBAHYAmAzlAAYAkA3i1QZMAX25QA-FBYQAbligAuMhWq16TVpxnDF02QszLaAKFMBjOCw7AoVOJjQBLNsnSKS2U1CgBpCk1mdi5bTGcWAHMoAB9dD0wAGh8oABFnCztGYJ0AJQgrTDZsAJBEqDCIyPxTfAAKAENMSJV4RD0cdMz8AEpiQibI8wcnV3cROv4oABYAJhUAcgALCAAbVbgFqFE+gHpd+kxMR1MRlzcOyagFuYXFlfXN7b2DrGPMYcdz8awrm9mHJt7msNlsdlB9lA4KQgA)

As you might have noticed it might have a drawback. It depends what are you expecting. If you want to forbid any numerical char in the key, you might wonna use this recursive type:

```js
type Numerical = number | `${number}`

type ReplaceNum<T, Cache extends string = ''> =
  T extends ''
  ? Cache
  : T extends `${infer Char}${infer Rest}`
  ? Char extends Numerical
  ? ReplaceNum<Rest, `${Cache}_`>
  : ReplaceNum<Rest, `${Cache}${Char}`>
  : never

type Test = ReplaceNum<'412foo'> // "___foo"

type ForbidNumbers<T extends Record<string | number, string>> = {
  [Prop in keyof T as ReplaceNum<Prop>]: T[Prop]
}

const forbidNumber = <
  Key extends string | number,
  Dict extends Record<Key, string>
>(arg: Dict extends ForbidNumbers<Dict> ? Dict : never) => arg

forbidNumber({ 42: 'hello' }) // error
forbidNumber({ '42': 'hello' }) // error

forbidNumber({ '42foo': 'hello' }) // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgVwLZQE4EsDGBDANjAXhgDtkAjNGAHxgAMASAb1KQtQF9bhRJYAlKBFzZMUREgA8AFQA0MAMIiAFrCgAPEFGIATAM4xdIDMQDmhGAHILAPkLAYMKTHWad%20q-ZgB%20BcqieALkdnDS09OiZ0YgAzSnklbA5ImMoBQ05PH3jEkNdw8TQsPEyYASERMWQJNJA5BkZFTBV2AH1aa0DSwWFRcWqoQzqmRubhhI52zuIoADc0bnBoRwGQczKeyskLABYARgAmaIB7I5sYAHpzmAAiFrvjo%20uF3hgAMSPUMnRtcTZdaVyYX0AkwH20EkMxjMNBYbDkkKiJmstiIjE8AG0AAqoI4QGBRGAAaygYCO0WC2GB3QqfWxuOsAF0glIsTiIAzgOxuKDiIYYMdPt9fpQiBJPABpEmAtwGIyI6gkchoGSeAAiWFWLiBXVBqHBkrA8Llpg61gAFIkTEF1ZhNaEZe9BT8lah-jaQLYfO6YEFpnNUABKQi2S3cAVfZ2sNBmxgwbb7IIWFS4XCnGDsIOXZyoHGoYDhoUumOWeMWRPJ1MWdOZq5oXNhj4R4WoYs7Q4nMuWCtpjMXK5HQlAA)

**`ReplaceNum`** - iterates through each char in an object key and checks whether it is stringified number or not.
If it is a number - replace it with underscore `_`, otherwise leave as is.

**`ForbidNumbers`** - iterates through each key and replace it wirh return type of `ReplaceNum`.

`Dict extends ForbidNumbers<Dict> ? Dict : never` - If `Dict` is the same object as after calling `ForbidNumbers` - allow using `Dict`, otherwise - return `never`

You can find more information about type validation in my articles [here](https://catchts.com/validators) and [here](https://catchts.com/type-negation)

---

There is no type negation in typescript. You can only validate it with help of conditional type, like `T extends number?never:T`. If `T` meets condition return `never` otherwise return `T`. Treat it as a replacement rather forbidding. Hence it is impossible to do smth like this `Record<not number, string>`

---

> And what I don't like is that when I pass number to index operator it is automatically converted to string

Please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

> An index signature property type must be either ‘string’ or ‘number’.

It is possible to support both types of indexers...
It is possible to support both types of indexers, but the type returned from a numeric indexer must be a subtype of the type returned from the string indexer. This is because when indexing with a `number`, JavaScript will actually convert that to a `string` before indexing into an object. That means that indexing with `100` (a `number`) is the same thing as indexing with `"100"` (a `string`), so the two need to be consistent.

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear enough.
I would like to have `'42'` as index in `Record`. So `{ '42': 'hello' }` is ok for me.

And what I don't like is that when I pass number to index operator in Record that has `string` keys it is automatically converted to string. I would like the compiler to throw an error in such situation somehow (on string  `console.log(r[42])`).

Comment: @SeleznevAnton I made an update

Comment: I got it. Many thanks.